# How to upload file in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Hi I created button 'UploadDocument' and with popup window after I upload documents using browse in popup window and click ok its should display documents names in 'aspx page' but not displaying  please suggest me how to do this...Below is the code

```
 <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
<h2>Upload Document</h2>
<a class="close" href="#">×</a>
<div class="content">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form1">
<label>Choose File
<asp:Fileupload ID="FileUpload1" class="multi" runat="server"></asp:Fileupload>
  <label> Destination Folder
     <asp:Fileupload ID="FileUpload2" class="multi" runat="server"></asp:Fileupload>
       <br />
       </label>
   </form>
<asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="OK" />
 <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>


    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) HandlesButton1.Click
           If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
       Try
             UploadDocument(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName, FileUpload1.FileName)
       Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
       End Try
   Else
   Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: as soon as you choose a file, you may see it's name right after BROWSE button. Explain what you need in detail, and also upload your full design code with code-behind.

Comment: After uploading files then click ok the popup window should close then the uploaded files should display in the aspx page near to Upload Document button then I will click Upload Document button to upload.....is it clear now the full code is what I uploaded above I don't have any view code regarding this.... can you please tell me what would be the view code for this

Comment: What does mean DESTINATION FOLDER? What do you mean that?

Comment: which button have OnClick BUTTON1_CLICK function?

Comment: Destination folder is nothing but destination path what exactly my aim is choose file is my source path and destination folder is my destination path button_1 is for Ok button

Answer (score 0):

if u don't have code behind file then how's it work! U have to code on button of file upload.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        this.FileUpload1.SaveAs("c:\\" + this.FileUpload1.FileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that in code behind file , Write code for onclick event of Button i.e. Button1

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {

                        string path = "D:/"+FileUpload1.FileName 
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
                }
         }
```